# ZSH: Get basename for for loop

Tags: for-loop, zsh

I'm trying to get the basename (without file extension) so that I can process a directory of audio files (.flac -> .m4a) quickly and and up with proper filenames.

So this works:

```
for i in *.flac;do ffmpeg -i $i -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 3 $i.m4a; done
```

But it leaves me with a file like like this: 
audiofile.flac.m4a

What I would like to do is just grab the "audiofile" part of the filename so that this works:

```
for i in *.flac;do ffmpeg -i $i.flac -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 3 $i.m4a; done
```

But I don't understand modifiers (apparently a ":t" modifier might get me the results?) or how to define variables on the for loop (for each file). Also, I see that there are many examples of how to do this with BASH, but I'm looking for something that works with zsh.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `zsh` you can use the [*Modifiers* from *History Expansion*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) with [*Parameter Expansions*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion). Each modifier is preceded by a colon: `${name:modifier}. The`r`modifier removes the extension, i.e. everything from - including - the last`.` to the end of the file name:

```
for i in *.flac; do 
    ffmpeg -i $i -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 3 ${i:r}.m4a
done
```

**Note:** the modifier `r` will remove any extension, not only ".flac".

A more portable (read: should work in any POSIX-compliant shell) and specific solution would be to use the *Parameter Expansion* `${name%pattern}`, which will remove the smallest string matching `pattern` from the end of the value of `name`. If `pattern` does not match the end of the value of `name`, the value will be returned unchanged:

```
for i in *.flac; do
    ffmpeg -i $i -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 3 ${i%.flac}.m4a
done
```

This will remove only ".flac" specifically from the end of the file names.